# Facebook's flash game Marvel Avengers randomly rebooting my comp

Tags: kubuntu, flash, facebook

I have Kuubntu 14.10 installed on my computer. It works perfectly, but if I launch Marvel Avengers games from Facebook, the game randomly reboots my computer without any warning. Does anyone has similar problem and what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest checking your power source and HW temperature. Flash games are heavy CPU consumers, which can cause troubles with power or overheating, both resulting in reboots/halts

Also look in syslog, which can contain interesting information. Check file /var/log/syslog or use Gnome log viewer...

Comment: But this is happening only with this game, other (flash) are working just fine and I've done detailed cleaning of my comp.